# Javascript not running in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html

It's been a while since I've touched web development, and I'm trying to get back into it. For some reason, however, I seem to be having trouble getting my JS scripts to run. I've tried linking a JS file using `<script src="script.js"></script>`, and even though the script file is in the same directory as my `index.html`, it seems to be ignoring it entirely. I've got some event listeners from jQuery, but at the very beginning of the code is a `console.log("sanity check");`.

So, after that didn't work, I tried writing the script *directly in the html file* like so:

```
<script>
     console.log("WHAT IS GOING ON?!");
     alert("It's finally working!");
</script>
```

and that STILL didn't work. Help!

Edit:

Here is the relevant HTML:

```
<head>
    <script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script>
      console.log("WHAT THE CRAP IS GOING ONNNN");
      alert("JS is running");
    </script>
</head>
```

Here is the JS,

```
console.log("sanity check");
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("Helloooo and good moonring!");
  $("#back").hover(function() {
    console.log ("*eyeroll* YES. I can hear you.");
    $("#back").attr("cursor", "pointer");
  }, function() {
    $("#back").attr("cursor", "default");
  });
});
```

None of it is working. I'm running it locally. The inspect tool in Chrome shows no errors whatsoever.

Edit 2:

I took a closer look at the code in the inspect tool. Still, nothing seeming to be wrong with it, but I have noticed that it isn't updating to the *saved* changes upon refreshing the page. This is clearly problematic, and very confusing. Also added `type="text/javascript"` and changed `script.js` to `./script.js` (and the same with the jQuery file).

Comment: u might miss to load the script using `onload` at `form` tag, try to search for it

Comment: Try specifying that the script is type JavaScript perhaps? Guessing.

Comment: How are you running your scripts?

Comment: @Se0ng11 what form?

Comment: Wow! That's weird. Tell us more about this html and is it from a server (http) or from your file directory (file)

Comment: @GROVER.in your `html`, there should have something like this `<html><form onload ="function()"></form></html>`

Comment: @Se0ng11 OP never mentioned a form. Just that his `script` wasn't being run by Chrome.

Comment: Make sure you aren't filtering messages in the console. Harder to do in Chrome than in Safari, but I've accidentally set the Error filter so regular console messages don't show.

Comment: @Will, how would I do that?

Comment: I added an "answer" with a screenshot. I doubt that's the problem but it's worth checking.

Comment: If the URL begins in http try "/script.js". If it's file:// try "./script.js"

Comment: Regarding saved changes: in Chrome when your dev tools are open click and hold the main refresh button and from the list choose the hard reload. The browser is caching your files.

Comment: @SydneyY Clicked hard reload. Nothing changed. How would I stop the browser from caching those local files?

Comment: Are you 100% sure you've opened the correct html file? :p

Comment: (Saw your solution; we've all been there, lol) To answer the reload: the browser has some rules and the server has some rules. But for yourself personally: you can change a setting in your dev tools to 'disable cache' which will work ONLY when the dev tools are open.

Comment: @SydneyY Thank you very much, for the grace you have given me, and the tip haha. Excited to get back into development.

Answer (score 1):

This snippet works, no?

```html
<script>
  console.log("WHAT THE CRAP IS GOING ONNNN");
  alert("JS is running");
</script>
```

Make sure these are checked and messages aren't hidden. Also maybe change "console.log" to "alert" just to make sure but check to make sure messages aren't being filtered out.

[image: Chrome Console Filter]

Comment: Checked. And Alert messages inserted. Still nothing. :(

Comment: Saw your edit. That code does not work. Made an update to the post with more info.

Comment: Did you (or your shifty roommate) disable Javascript? https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/disable

Comment: No... I saw it in the settings earlier, and the box was unchecked. This makes no sense!

Comment: Yeah, I'm stumped. That code in the snippet pops an alert and writes a console message. What did you do, Ethan? Fess up, Ethan!

Comment: As expected, I made a dumb mistake. Answer posted!

Answer (score 1):

Solved! Earlier, before I came across this issue, I decided to change my folder from "Web Design Project" to "WebDesignProject", because there were some things I wanted to look at in Terminal. Apparently my text editor, Atom, decided that this meant that the folder I had left open called "Web Design Project" was an *entirely different folder.* Those changes that I made were then mapped not to "WebDesignProject," but instead a new folder, once again named "Web Design Project."

In conclusion. Never put spaces in your project folder name. And, when you change the folder name, restart EVERYTHING. Atom should fix this phenomenon.

Comment: Hmm, I think that's more an own-goal situation than an Atom problem!